# Save a list of sjPlot::tab_model tables ta on a word file or a RMarkdown file

Tags: r, save, r-markdown, cpu-word

I have this list of tables that I've created by sjPlot

[image]

If I would like to create a report with RMarkdown or save them as a word file, would am I supposed to do?

Comment: Can you suggest a sufficient length to use?

Comment: I guess the `tab_model` output is html.  So, have you tried `iwalk(yourlist, print)`

Comment: they actually are html. I've run that code but I am not that sure the thing that is supposed to do

Comment: It actually turns me back the last table in the viewer session

Comment: That is exactky the one you can see here in the image I've uploaded

Comment: try the code in the solution i posted below.  It is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to specify `results = 'asis'` in the chunk along with using `knit_print`

````
---
title: "Title"
output: html_document

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, echo = FALSE}
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(sjPlot))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(sjmisc))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(sjlabelled))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(purrr))

# sample data
data("efc")
efc <- as_factor(efc, c161sex, c172code)
```

## R Markdown

```{r data, echo = FALSE}

m1 <- lm(barthtot ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)
m2 <- lm(neg_c_7 ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + e17age, data = efc)
lst1 <- list(tab_model(m1), tab_model(m2))
```

```{r model out, echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
for(i in seq_along(lst1)) cat(knitr::knit_print(lst1[[1]]))
# or use
#iwalk(lst1, ~ cat(knitr::knit_print(.x)))
```
````

-output

[image]

Comment: Knitting to Html-file works right, but with Word I have problems. You too?

Comment: Thanks. I don't know wether I'll be able to do with my code. Btw this is a html_doc. Is there any way to create a word one?

Comment: I didn't run it yet

Comment: @mały_statystyczny It does create in word, but the formatting is an issue

Comment: @mały_statystyczny we can open html-file in the word, but it look a little average

Comment: @akrun yes, only copypaste can help; a sentence from site of the author of the library: ```(HTML is the only output-format, you can’t (directly) create a LaTex or PDF output from tab_model() and related table-functions. However, it is possible to easily export the tables into Microsoft Word or Libre Office Writer.)``` Your solution is nice and you deserve +1 ;)

Comment: @mały_statystyczny if the function doesn't have that ability it is better to use html option or you may have to use different packages.  There are many packages that does it i.e. look for `gtsummary` or flextable

Comment: Actually I'll attempt another time. For now I'm meeting issue to create the report even in html format

Comment: @mały_statystyczny Put a comment on ```cat(knitr::knit_print(lst1[[1]]))``` and uncomment next string ```#iwalk(lst1, ~ cat(knitr::knit_print(.x)))```.

Comment: @manro I meant either one of them will work.  It was just to give another option

Comment: @akrun with ```cat...``` i had problems too

Comment: @manro I tested both and it is working.  May be due to some version differences

Comment: Maybe I made it. There is a last issue I need to solve. When I try creating an html file, that turns me back the following error `The name of the input file cannot contain the special shell characters: [ <>()|\:&;#?*'] (attempted to copy to a version without those characters 'report-1.Rmd' however that file already exists)`. Does anyone know what I have to check'?

Comment: @mały_statystyczny Try changing the `-` to `_` (underscore).  Mostly `-` would be an issue or else you may have to backquote ``report-1.Rmd`` instead of single quote.  The backquote here is not working in the comment

Comment: @akrun Thank you so much for the discussion. I was able to fix my issues by the example you've provided and your comments as well. If you reckon this question helpful, feel free to just vote it up. Btw I've pubblished a new question to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69830732/how-to-apply-to-al-list-of-models-lsmeans-function-to-get-pairwise-comparisons and maybe you can provide your contribute.

Comment: @manro thanks for your comments. If this seems to be helful, if you want you can vote it up. Feel free also to give your contribute to this question, if you'd like to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69830732/how-to-apply-to-al-list-of-models-lsmeans-function-to-get-pairwise-comparisons

Comment: @mały_statystyczny thanks.  I vote it up.  Can you please clarify the objects used there. thanks